# Adicionar valor no name

Tags: php, while

Tenho um while, e queria que a cada laço fosse adicionado um valor diferente no name, dois dois campos select.

Ex:
Primeiro laço primeiro campo vem: 
semanacrianca1

Primeiro laço primeiro campo vem: 
semanacrianca2

Alguém tem alguma ideia como faço isso?

Abaixo o código que tenho:

```
<?php  
$i = 1;
while ($i <= 2) {
?>
<div class="container">
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>Dados da primeira Criança</h1> 
<form action="">

  <div class="semanas-e-periodos">

     <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Semana</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" name="semanacrianca1">
      <option value="1semana">1º Semana</option>
      <option value="2semana">2º Semana</option>
      <option value="3semana">3º Semana</option>
      <option value="4semana">4º Semana</option>
      </select>
  </div>


     <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Semana</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" name="qtdcriancas">
      <option value="1">1 Criança</option>
      <option value="2">2 Crianças</option>
      <option value="3">3 Crianças</option>
      <option value="4">4 Crianças</option>
      <option value="5">5 Crianças</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  </div>

</form>

  </div>

<?
$i++;
}

?>
```

Comment: name="semanacrianca<?php echo $i">

Comment: ops name="semanacrianca<?php echo $i ?>">

Comment: Cara muito bom deu certo, obrigado @LeoCaracciolo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tente concatenar assim:
1. Crie um contador para a array semanacrianca e uma array para qtdcriancas;
em seguida o laço de repetição irá acessá-las

```
<select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" name="<?php $semanacrianca1[$a] ?>">
```

">

++$a;
++$b;

agora vai da sua lógica pra fazer funfar

Comment: Obrigado @adiel-esdras deu certo também a sua forma.
Vlw mesmo.

Answer (score 0):

Faça assim:

```
<?php  
 $i = 1;
 while ($i <= 2) {
?>
<div class="container">
 <div class="jumbotron">
  <h1>Dados da primeira Criança</h1> 
<form action="paginaAcao">

<div class="semanas-e-periodos">

<div class="form-group">
<label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Semana</label>
<?php for($i=1;$i<=2;$i++){ ?>
  <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" name="semanacrianca<?php echo $i?>">
   <option value="1semana">1º Semana</option>
   <option value="2semana">2º Semana</option>
   <option value="3semana">3º Semana</option>
   <option value="4semana">4º Semana</option>
  </select>
</div>
<?php } ?>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Semana</label>
  <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" name="qtdcriancas">
    <option value="1">1 Criança</option>
    <option value="2">2 Crianças</option>
    <option value="3">3 Crianças</option>
    <option value="4">4 Crianças</option>
    <option value="5">5 Crianças</option>
 </select>
</div>

</div>

</form>

</div>

<?php
 $i++;
 }
?>
```

Comment: E method="METODO"